# Add Path+ Parameters to Response Fields

Tags: java, apache, web-services

I´m making a Web Service, using Java and Glassfish as server.

I´m also using Apache Server for Processing HTTP requests, i.e, when I make a request, I´m able to get the standard informations, like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1 [\r][\n]"
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)[\r][\n]
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=efc5aa919b55321d3aeaf2c9b3b6; Path=/context; HttpOnly[\r][\n]
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 15:26:40 GMT[\r][\n]
Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="file"[\r][\n]
Content-Language: [\r][\n]
Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]
Content-Length: 1090[\r][\n]
SOAPAction: ""[\r][\n]
Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]
Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]
```

One Example of a Web Operation that I developed is:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "someoperation")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void makeHappen(@WebParam(name = "req") Object obj,
       @WebParam(name = "resp", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<String> response) {

To List of information that I get, I want to add own specifications, like:


--> OperationName: someOperation
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]
    Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1 [\r][\n]"
    X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)[\r][\n]
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=efc5aa919b55321d3aeaf2c9b3b6; Path=/context; HttpOnly[\r][\n]
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]
    Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 15:26:40 GMT[\r][\n]
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]
    WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="file"[\r][\n]
    Content-Language: [\r][\n]
    Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]
    Content-Length: 1090[\r][\n]
    SOAPAction: ""[\r][\n]
    Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]
    Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For WebSphere Application Server:

Refer to the documentation and examples in [Sending transport headers with JAX-WS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_cookiejaxws.html)

> Here is a short programming example that illustrates how request
>   transport headers are sent by a JAX-WS Web services client
>   application:

```
public class MyApplicationClass {
    // Inject an instance of the service's port-type.
    @WebServiceRef(EchoService.class)
    private EchoPortType port;

    // This method will invoke  the web service operation and send transport headers on the request.
    public void invokeService() {

        // Set up the Map that will contain the request headers.
        Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader1”, “This is a string value”);
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader2”, new Integer(33));
        requestHeaders.put(“MyHeader3”, new Boolean(true));

        // Set the Map as a property on the RequestContext.
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES, requestHeaders);

        // Invoke the web services operation.
        String result = port.echoString(“Hello, world!”);
    }
}
```

> Here is a short programming example that illustrates how response
>   transport headers are sent by a JAX-WS Web services endpoint
>   implementation class:

```
@WebService
public class EchoServiceImpl implements EchoServicePortType {

    // Inject an instance of WebServiceContext so we can retrieve
    // the MessageContext for each invocation of this endpoint.
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext ctxt;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public EchoServiceImpl() {
        ....
    }

    public String echoString(String input) {
        String result = “Echo result: “ + input;

        // Retrieve the MessageContext from the injected WebServiceContext.
        MessageContext mc = ctxt.getMessageContext();

        // Send some headers back in the response message.
        Map<String, Object> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        responseHeaders.put("MyHeader1", "This is a string response value");
        responseHeaders.put("MyHeader2", new Integer(33));
        responseHeaders.put("MyHeader3”, new Boolean(false));

        // Set the response header Map on the MessageContext.
        mc.put(com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES, responseHeaders);

        return result;
    }
}
```

- For GlassFish Application Server:

You can get the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext` and from it `javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext`. Then add to the `MessageContext` your headers, something like this:

```
...
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("OperationName", someOperation);
messageContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers)
...
```

Also you can try to append the HTTP header to the request by using this approach:

```
...
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch =  
 service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);    
Map<String, List<String>> headers = 
      new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
headers.put("OperationName", someOperation);    
dispatch.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
  headers);
...
```

See Also:

- [How to modify request headers in a J2EE web application](https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/)
- [How to add HTTP header to SOAP Webservice Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379682/how-to-add-http-header-to-soap-webservice-glassfish)

Comment: com.ibm.websphere.webservices, how to make this for glassfish?