# Use WebServiceContext outside WebService

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, ejb

In my Web service, I have:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "myservice")
public class ServiceName{

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;
```

In a stateless class I want to use the same operation:

```
@Stateless
public class MakeHappen{

 @Resource
        private WebServiceContext context;
```

But I receive an EJB exception. How can I inject this resource, outside webservice?

Comment: What information specifically are you trying to get from the `WebServiceContext `

Comment: You already answered to my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK no, only in the context of a Webservice.

See [Interface WebServiceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html)

> A `WebServiceContext` makes it possible for a *Webservice* endpoint
>   implementation class to access message context and security
>   information relative to a request being served. Typically a
>   `WebServiceContext` is injected into an endpoint implementation class
>   using the `@Resource` annotation.

In your case, you should to decorate stateless EJB as Webservice. Open methods of the stateless EJB can be represented as Webservices.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class MakeHappen {

@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

...
```

Comment: There is a similar object to webservicecontext that can be used on ejb container?

Comment: Regarding, to my last question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105806/add-path-parameters-to-response-fields/30106595#30106595, it´s possible to use some context to determine my request path and its parameters?

Comment: Yes, I understand differences between containers. It´s not my question. How can I get SOAP content using a filter - My main question question is still the same. How can I add a header dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Web service endpoint belongs to a web tier and is managed by a web container (See [Java EE 7 tutorial 6.1 Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/webapp001.htm#GEYSJ) for more info).

Enterprise bean on the other hand is a business logic component. It is managed by EJB container ([Java EE 7 tutorial 32.1  What Is an Enterprise Bean?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro001.htm#GIPMB)).

This means that enterprise bean could not have WebServiceContext injected as it is managed by different container. This would also make no sense as EJB container have no WebServiceContext.

Answer (score 1):

I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789637/webservicecontext-is-it-there-a-way-to-inject-it-any-where-appart-from-my-webse/47831859#47831859) and this is how I solved it:

```
WebServiceContext wscontext = null;
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    wscontext = (WebServiceContext) ctx.lookup("java:comp/WebServiceContext");
} catch (NamingException e) {

}
```