# WebServiceContext: Is it there a way to inject it any where appart from my WebService?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I'm trying get the jax-ws `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext`. I'm able to do it in my Web service this way:

```
@WebService
public class Service extends BaseService {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @WebMethod
    public responseExample example(....) {...}

}
```

I want to get this bean any where else in my code. Would it work if I use spring?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123148/use-webservicecontext-outside-webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time trying different ways, this is how I managed to do it like this:

```
WebServiceContext wscontext = null;
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    wscontext = (WebServiceContext) ctx.lookup("java:comp/WebServiceContext");
} catch (NamingException e) {

}
```